# Optimize Pandas Memory Usage

Tags: python, pandas, database

I'm trying to import the data. I'm getting `Memory Error`. I increased the virtual memory, and the data size is 2.71 GB. I thought about setting the data types in advance to optimize memory consumption, so I found this site: [Optimize Pandas Memory Usage for Large Datasets](https://link.medium.com/tMf8l7rv1qb)

```
base_path = pathlib.Path('dataset')

base_airbnb = pd.DataFrame()

for file in base_path.iterdir():
    df = pd.read_csv(r'dataset\{}'.format(file.name))
    base_airbnb = base_airbnb.append(df)
    
display(base_airbnb)
```

How to set pandas column types to decrease memory consumption?

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, `df.append` is deprecated and `pd.concat` should be used instead.

```
base_path = pathlib.Path('dataset')
base_airbnb = []

for file in base_path.iterdir():
    base_airbnb.append(pd.read_csv(rf'dataset\{file.name}', dtype={'a': np.float64, 'b': np.int32, 'c': 'Int64'})

base_airbnb = pd.concat(base_airbnb)
```

As for how to set dtypes... follow the pattern given in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv).

- `{'a': np.float64, 'b': np.int32, 'c': 'Int64'}`

Comment: I don't understand how the error persists... Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory